# How can I add Continuous parallax effect using tilemap layer in Phaser?

Tags: phaser-framework

Is there a way to make a tilemap layer use a continuous parallax effect in Phaser?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have a Tilemap layer be "endless", no, they have fixed dimensions. A parallax effect is achieved by just setting different scroll speeds on the layers.

Comment: I am having hard time regarding my issue, in my game some random obstacles come to player path horizontally, i am trying to add them to a group but as soon as two obstacles are spawned the following error is thrown don't no how to overcome it.

error: `unable to get property reset for undefined or null reference`

Answer (score 0):

It won't work as a TilemapLayer but it *will* work if you convert the TilemapLayer to a TileSprite and then scroll that.